# Can't open/select a table created with another user

Tags: oracle, permissions

I created a table with one user and cannot read or select the table after I log in with another user.

- Database: Oracle
- Name: TestDatabase
- User name: sysadmin

Another user "user1" was created in the same schema with admin rights but it is not able to see tables created by the first user.

Comment: You need to grant dba to do that by connecting as SYS user. `grant dba to testdba`

Comment: @learningloop already given grant dba permission but it can not able to access existing database's tables.

Comment: thats strange. Did you try to access the table with schema name? For example: `select * from scott.emp`

Comment: yeah its saying table or view doesn't exist

Comment: @learningloop how can I give grant all on whole db to that user

Comment: it should have worked try to select come other schema and tablename combination. In your case the scott schema might not be existing.

Comment: @learningloop I login with already created user and created one more user with admin role.but exisiting user login can able to see all the tables but newly created user can not able to see any single table in that database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66010/discussion-between-learningloop-and-vim).

Comment: Why grant all privileges to a user when it would be quicker to give someone the sys password. Essentially you are creating a user that has all of the privileges of sys, but is called something else. Such a user can create as many users as they want with as many privileges as they want, hence they might as well be sys.

Comment: `DBA` is a role.  Did you perhaps not make it default for TESTDBA?  As SYS, try: `SELECT default_role FROM dba_role_privs WHERE grantee='TESTDBA' AND granted_role='DBA';` should return `YES`.  If not, then `ALTER USER TESTDBA DEFAULT ROLE ALL;`

Comment: Please post what is exactly your problem From the comments I conclude that your problem is that you create a table with one user and cannot read the select the table after you log in with another user. If this is your problem than be so kind and change the text of your question.

Comment: @miracle173 yes it is the same problem bro that you mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

Login as `SYSDBA` and you need to do `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO USER` to the newly created user.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create user test_all_privs identified by test_all_privs;

User created.

SQL> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO test_all_privs;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn test_all_privs@pdborcl
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> conn sys@pdborcl as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> drop user test_all_privs;

User dropped.

SQL>
```

Comment: @LalitKumarBi tried that but it is still not showing tables.count is giving 14 for scott.emp